# ffmpeg giving error on launch in Mac OS X Lion 10.7.1

Tags: macos, homebrew

I installed ffmpeg 0.8.5 in my Mac OS X Lion 10.7.1 with Homebrew

```
brew install --use-gcc ffmpeg
```

It installed without any error. But, now when I run, it gives the following -

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/0.8.5/lib/libavdevice.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
  Reason: Incompatible library version: ffmpeg requires version 53.0.0 or later, but libavdevice.dylib provides version 52.0.0
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using:

```
$ brew update && brew install `brew outdated` && brew cleanup
```

This [script](https://gist.github.com/676232) will also help you track down changes on libraries that are needed.

If you those don't work try:

```
$ brew doctor (check your setup for common problems)
$ brew missing (to check installed packages for missing deps)
```

brew doctor checks your setup for common problems, brew missing checks installed packages for missing deps.

You can always start fresh (which should take care of all the problems):

```
$ brew uninstall --force `brew deps ffmpeg`
$ brew install ffmpeg
```

then

```
$ brew update
```

Comment: Didn't work for me :( but still thanks for your effort :)

Comment: I've added a couple more solutions to try,

Comment: `brew uninstall --force `brew deps ffmpeg`` & reinstalling did the trick for me, though it also uninstalled git and the reinstall didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I ran: 
`brew install libav`

then after it complained about symlinking:
`brew link --overwrite avconv`

Works now.